# "String cannot be converted to int" red line error

Tags: java

I'm new here and at Java. It's been 3 weeks in since my class Object Oriented Programming began at my campus. I was referring to a pic of my classmate for my coding assignment but for some reason, I got a red line error stating "String cannot be converted to int" for line 25 and 33. When I checked, all of the lines in the pic has no red lines but for mine, there is so I'm puzzled. So if you can point out what I'm missing here, I'd appreciate your help.

```
package usecourse01102020;
```

import java.util.Scanner;

public class UseCourse01102020 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s= new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter department");
    String dept = s.next();
    System.out.println("Enter subject");
    String subject = s.next();
    System.out.println("Enter credit");
    int credit = s.nextInt();
    if (dept.equals("ISC")||dept.equals("ENT")||
            dept.equals("MSG")||dept.equals("SESS"))
        
{
    LabSubject l = new LabSubject(dept,subject,credit);
     System.out.println(l.calculationfee());
    // fee = (credit*120)+50;
}
    
    
else
{
    MSUCourse m = new MSUCourse(dept,subject,credit);
     System.out.println(m.calculationfee());
    // fee = credit*120
}

}
```

}

The errors are at line 25 LabSubject l and line MSUCourse m

package usecourse01102020;

public class MSUCourse extends UseCourse01102020{

```
String d,s;
int c;

MSUCourse(int a, String dept, String subject){
    
    c = a;
    d = dept;
    s = subject;
}

int calculationfee()
{
    return c*120;
}
```

}

package usecourse01102020;

public class LabSubject extends MSUCourse{

```
int c;

LabSubject(int a, String dept, String subject){
    
    super(a,dept,subject);
    c = a;
}

int calculationfee()
{
    return (c*120)+50;
}
```

}

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: [Please do not post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). You should provide a [mre] in the question itself (i.e. as properly formatted text). Also, Java _is not_ JavaScript.

Comment: You probably have a wrong constructor in your classes. Check that again.

Comment: @Slaw I've changed the image to code. Understood.

Comment: Could it mean that LabSubject and MSUCourse are not initialized?

Comment: Probably because you give your parameters to the constructor in the wrong order… The department should be given as 2nd parameter, and the credit as first.

Comment: @StéphaneVeyret Oh. I thought I can just place it anywhere. So, I have to place it in proper order. My bad there. I just ran the code and it was successful. Thank you.

Comment: @YN27 you cannot expect the computer to guess what you want to do. There are some programming languages where you can provide parameters in any order (this is not the case for Java), but you must then give the parameters name. Also, can you accept my answer below so that your question becomes resolved?

Answer (score 2):

In

```java
LabSubject(int a, String dept, String subject){
    
    super(a,dept,subject);
    c = a;
}
```

You expect department to be given as 2nd parameter. I suppose your `a` (you should give a better name) is the credit, which should be provided as 1st parameter.

When you create the object

```java
LabSubject l = new LabSubject(dept,subject,credit);
```

You don't respect this order!

Answer (score 0):

You are passing int value instead of string value

In the arguments of lab subject change int a ,into String a,

```
LabSubject(String a, String dept, String subject)
```

Also change this

```
MSUCourse(String a, String dept, String subject)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should casting the data, strig cast to int using parse function

Answer (score 0):

you need to follow the order of that constructor parameters

**required** is LabSubject(int,string,string);

**you are passing** LabSubject(string,string,int);

check in both constructor.

try like **LabSubject(credit,dept,subject);**